# Add shiny gradient to tickets with javascript

Tags: javascript, gradient, rgb

I'm trying to give each of the falling objects a gradient to make them look like shiny gold tickets.

I have a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tands/pen/qRrBja)

I forked the pen from another repo and all i've changed in the background colour and the ticket colour.

This is the part of the code that control the colour. How do I add the gradient?

```
      var colorThemes = [
        function() {
          //return color(200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0);
          return color(218,165,32);
        }, function() {
          var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(200, black, black);
        }, function() {
          var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(black, 200, black);
        }, function() {
          var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(black, black, 200);
        }, function() {
          return color(200, 100, 200 * random()|0);
        }, function() {
          return color(200 * random()|0, 200, 200);
        }, function() {
          var black = 256 * random()|0; return color(black, black, black);
        }, function() {
          return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 1 : 2]();
        }, function() {
          return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 3 : 5]();
        }, function() {
          return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 2 : 4]();
        }
      ];

      function color(r, g, b) {
        return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
      }
```

```js
'use strict';

// If set to true, the user must press
// UP UP DOWN ODWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT A B
// to trigger the confetti with a random color theme.
// Otherwise the confetti constantly falls.
var onlyOnKonami = false;

$(function() {
  // Globals
  var $window = $(window)
    , random = Math.random
    , cos = Math.cos
    , sin = Math.sin
    , PI = Math.PI
    , PI2 = PI * 2
    , timer = undefined
    , frame = undefined
    , confetti = [];

  // Settings
  var konami = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65]
    , pointer = 0;

  var particles = 150
    , spread = 10
    , sizeMin = 3
    , sizeMax = 40 - sizeMin
    , eccentricity = 10
    , deviation = 100
    , dxThetaMin = -.1
    , dxThetaMax = -dxThetaMin - dxThetaMin
    , dyMin = .13
    , dyMax = .18
    , dThetaMin = .4
    , dThetaMax = .7 - dThetaMin;

  var colorThemes = [
    function() {
      //return color(200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0);
      return color(218,165,32);
    }, function() {
      var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(200, black, black);
    }, function() {
      var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(black, 200, black);
    }, function() {
      var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(black, black, 200);
    }, function() {
      return color(200, 100, 200 * random()|0);
    }, function() {
      return color(200 * random()|0, 200, 200);
    }, function() {
      var black = 256 * random()|0; return color(black, black, black);
    }, function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 1 : 2]();
    }, function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 3 : 5]();
    }, function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 2 : 4]();
    }
  ];
  function color(r, g, b) {
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  }

  // Cosine interpolation
  function interpolation(a, b, t) {
    return (1-cos(PI*t))/2 * (b-a) + a;
  }

  // Create a 1D Maximal Poisson Disc over [0, 1]
  var radius = 1/eccentricity, radius2 = radius+radius;
  function createPoisson() {
    // domain is the set of points which are still available to pick from
    // D = union{ [d_i, d_i+1] | i is even }
    var domain = [radius, 1-radius], measure = 1-radius2, spline = [0, 1];
    while (measure) {
      var dart = measure * random(), i, l, interval, a, b, c, d;

      // Find where dart lies
      for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
        a = domain[i], b = domain[i+1], interval = b-a;
        if (dart < measure+interval) {
          spline.push(dart += a-measure);
          break;
        }
        measure += interval;
      }
      c = dart-radius, d = dart+radius;

      // Update the domain
      for (i = domain.length-1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
        l = i-1, a = domain[l], b = domain[i];
        // c---d          c---d  Do nothing
        //   c-----d  c-----d    Move interior
        //   c--------------d    Delete interval
        //         c--d          Split interval
        //       a------b
        if (a >= c && a < d)
          if (b > d) domain[l] = d; // Move interior (Left case)
          else domain.splice(l, 2); // Delete interval
        else if (a < c && b > c)
          if (b <= d) domain[i] = c; // Move interior (Right case)
          else domain.splice(i, 0, c, d); // Split interval
      }

      // Re-measure the domain
      for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2)
        measure += domain[i+1]-domain[i];
    }

    return spline.sort();
  }

  // Create the overarching container
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.style.position = 'fixed';
  container.style.top      = '0';
  container.style.left     = '0';
  container.style.width    = '100%';
  container.style.height   = '0';
  container.style.overflow = 'visible';
  container.style.zIndex   = '9999';

  // Confetto constructor
  function Confetto(theme) {
    this.frame = 0;
    this.outer = document.createElement('div');
    this.inner = document.createElement('div');
    this.outer.appendChild(this.inner);

    var outerStyle = this.outer.style, innerStyle = this.inner.style;
    outerStyle.position = 'absolute';
    outerStyle.width  = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
    outerStyle.height = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
    innerStyle.width  = '100%';
    innerStyle.height = '100%';
    innerStyle.backgroundColor = theme();

    outerStyle.perspective = '100px';
    outerStyle.transform = 'rotate(' + (360 * random()) + 'deg)';
    this.axis = 'rotate3D(' +
      cos(360 * random()) + ',' +
      cos(360 * random()) + ',0,';
    this.theta = 360 * random();
    this.dTheta = dThetaMin + dThetaMax * random();
    innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';

    this.x = $window.width() * random();
    this.y = -deviation;
    this.dx = sin(dxThetaMin + dxThetaMax * random());
    this.dy = dyMin + dyMax * random();
    outerStyle.left = this.x + 'px';
    outerStyle.top  = this.y + 'px';

    // Create the periodic spline
    this.splineX = createPoisson();
    this.splineY = [];
    for (var i = 1, l = this.splineX.length-1; i < l; ++i)
      this.splineY[i] = deviation * random();
    this.splineY[0] = this.splineY[l] = deviation * random();

    this.update = function(height, delta) {
      this.frame += delta;
      this.x += this.dx * delta;
      this.y += this.dy * delta;
      this.theta += this.dTheta * delta;

      // Compute spline and convert to polar
      var phi = this.frame % 7777 / 7777, i = 0, j = 1;
      while (phi >= this.splineX[j]) i = j++;
      var rho = interpolation(
        this.splineY[i],
        this.splineY[j],
        (phi-this.splineX[i]) / (this.splineX[j]-this.splineX[i])
      );
      phi *= PI2;

      outerStyle.left = this.x + rho * cos(phi) + 'px';
      outerStyle.top  = this.y + rho * sin(phi) + 'px';
      innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';
      return this.y > height+deviation;
    };
  }

  function poof() {
    if (!frame) {
      // Append the container
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      // Add confetti
      var theme = colorThemes[onlyOnKonami ? colorThemes.length * random()|0 : 0]
        , count = 0;
      (function addConfetto() {
        if (onlyOnKonami && ++count > particles)
          return timer = undefined;

        var confetto = new Confetto(theme);
        confetti.push(confetto);
        container.appendChild(confetto.outer);
        timer = setTimeout(addConfetto, spread * random());
      })(0);

      // Start the loop
      var prev = undefined;
      requestAnimationFrame(function loop(timestamp) {
        var delta = prev ? timestamp - prev : 0;
        prev = timestamp;
        var height = $window.height();

        for (var i = confetti.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
          if (confetti[i].update(height, delta)) {
            container.removeChild(confetti[i].outer);
            confetti.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }

        if (timer || confetti.length)
          return frame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // Cleanup
        document.body.removeChild(container);
        frame = undefined;
      });
    }
  }

  $window.keydown(function(event) {
    pointer = konami[pointer] === event.which
      ? pointer+1
      : +(event.which === konami[0]);
    if (pointer === konami.length) {
      pointer = 0;
      poof();
    }
  });
  
  if (!onlyOnKonami) poof();
});
```

```css
html {
   height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #d09d42;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #efc466, #d09d42);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: very interesting question check out this http://codepen.io/vignesh200/pen/MJpQpr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify method Confetto() to change the color of the divI've added the following javascript after **innerStyle.backgroundColor = theme()**:

```
    function  Confetto(){

    //Code
    innerStyle.backgroundColor = theme()
    innerStyle.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + theme() + " , yellow)";
     innerStyle.border = "thick solid #FFFB00";
     innerStyle.borderWidth = "thin";
     //Rest of the code
    }
```

Check out this :

```js
// JavaScript source code
'use strict';

// If set to true, the user must press
// UP UP DOWN ODWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT A B
// to trigger the confetti with a random color theme.
// Otherwise the confetti constantly falls.
var onlyOnKonami = false;

$(function () {
    // Globals
    var $window = $(window),
      random = Math.random,
      cos = Math.cos,
      sin = Math.sin,
      PI = Math.PI,
      PI2 = PI * 2,
      timer = undefined,
      frame = undefined,
      confetti = [];

    // Settings
    var konami = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65],
    //var konami = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      pointer = 0;

    var particles = 10,
      spread = 10,
      sizeMin = 3,
      sizeMax = 40 - sizeMin,
      eccentricity = 10,
      deviation = 100,
      dxThetaMin = -.1,
      dxThetaMax = -dxThetaMin - dxThetaMin,
      dyMin = .13,
      dyMax = .18,
      dThetaMin = .4,
      dThetaMax = .7 - dThetaMin;

    var colorThemes = [
      function () {
          //return color(200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0);
          return color(218, 165, 32);
      },
      function () {
          var black = 200 * random() | 0;
          return color(200, black, black);
      },
      function () {
          var black = 200 * random() | 0;
          return color(black, 200, black);
      },
      function () {
          var black = 200 * random() | 0;
          return color(black, black, 200);
      },
      function () {
          return color(200, 100, 200 * random() | 0);
      },
      function () {
          return color(200 * random() | 0, 200, 200);
      },
      function () {
          var black = 256 * random() | 0;
          return color(black, black, black);
      },
      function () {
          return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 1 : 2]();
      },
      function () {
          return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 3 : 5]();
      },
      function () {
          return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 2 : 4]();
      }
    ];

    function color(r, g, b) {
        return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
    }

    // Cosine interpolation
    function interpolation(a, b, t) {
        return (1 - cos(PI * t)) / 2 * (b - a) + a;
    }

    // Create a 1D Maximal Poisson Disc over [0, 1]
    var radius = 1 / eccentricity,
      radius2 = radius + radius;

    function createPoisson() {
        // domain is the set of points which are still available to pick from
        // D = union{ [d_i, d_i+1] | i is even }
        var domain = [radius, 1 - radius],
          measure = 1 - radius2,
          spline = [0, 1];
        while (measure) {
            var dart = measure * random(),
              i, l, interval, a, b, c, d;

            // Find where dart lies
            for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
                a = domain[i], b = domain[i + 1], interval = b - a;
                if (dart < measure + interval) {
                    spline.push(dart += a - measure);
                    break;
                }
                measure += interval;
            }
            c = dart - radius, d = dart + radius;

            // Update the domain
            for (i = domain.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
                l = i - 1, a = domain[l], b = domain[i];
                // c---d          c---d  Do nothing
                //   c-----d  c-----d    Move interior
                //   c--------------d    Delete interval
                //         c--d          Split interval
                //       a------b
                if (a >= c && a < d)
                    if (b > d) domain[l] = d; // Move interior (Left case)
                    else domain.splice(l, 2); // Delete interval
                else if (a < c && b > c)
                    if (b <= d) domain[i] = c; // Move interior (Right case)
                    else domain.splice(i, 0, c, d); // Split interval
            }

            // Re-measure the domain
            for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2)
                measure += domain[i + 1] - domain[i];
        }

        return spline.sort();
    }

    // Create the overarching container
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.style.position = 'fixed';
    container.style.top = '0';
    container.style.left = '0';
    container.style.width = '100%';
    container.style.height = '0';
    container.style.overflow = 'visible';
    container.style.zIndex = '9999';

    // Confetto constructor
    function Confetto(theme) {
        this.frame = 0;
        this.outer = document.createElement('div');
        this.inner = document.createElement('div');
        this.outer.appendChild(this.inner);

        var outerStyle = this.outer.style,
          innerStyle = this.inner.style;
        outerStyle.position = 'absolute';
        outerStyle.width = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
        outerStyle.height = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
        innerStyle.width = '100%';
        innerStyle.height = '100%';
        var f = theme();
        innerStyle.backgroundColor = theme();
        innerStyle.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + theme() + " , yellow)";
        innerStyle.border = "thick solid #FFFB00";
        innerStyle.borderWidth = "thin";
        outerStyle.perspective = '100px';
        outerStyle.transform = 'rotate(' + (360 * random()) + 'deg)';
        this.axis = 'rotate3D(' +
          cos(360 * random()) + ',' +
          cos(360 * random()) + ',0,';
        this.theta = 360 * random();
        this.dTheta = dThetaMin + dThetaMax * random();
        innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';

        this.x = $window.width() * random();
        this.y = -deviation;
        this.dx = sin(dxThetaMin + dxThetaMax * random());
        this.dy = dyMin + dyMax * random();
        outerStyle.left = this.x + 'px';
        outerStyle.top = this.y + 'px';

        // Create the periodic spline
        this.splineX = createPoisson();
        this.splineY = [];
        for (var i = 1, l = this.splineX.length - 1; i < l; ++i)
            this.splineY[i] = deviation * random();
        this.splineY[0] = this.splineY[l] = deviation * random();

        this.update = function (height, delta) {
            this.frame += delta;
            this.x += this.dx * delta;
            this.y += this.dy * delta;
            this.theta += this.dTheta * delta;

            // Compute spline and convert to polar
            var phi = this.frame % 7777 / 7777,
              i = 0,
              j = 1;
            while (phi >= this.splineX[j]) i = j++;
            var rho = interpolation(
              this.splineY[i],
              this.splineY[j],
              (phi - this.splineX[i]) / (this.splineX[j] - this.splineX[i])
            );
            phi *= PI2;

            outerStyle.left = this.x + rho * cos(phi) + 'px';
            outerStyle.top = this.y + rho * sin(phi) + 'px';
            innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';
            return this.y > height + deviation;
        };
    }

    function poof() {
        if (!frame) {
            // Append the container
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            // Add confetti
            var theme = colorThemes[onlyOnKonami ? colorThemes.length * random() | 0 : 0],
              count = 0;
            (function addConfetto() {
                if (onlyOnKonami && ++count > particles)
                    return timer = undefined;

                var confetto = new Confetto(theme);
                confetti.push(confetto);
                container.appendChild(confetto.outer);
                timer = setTimeout(addConfetto, spread * random());
            })(0);

            // Start the loop
            var prev = undefined;
            requestAnimationFrame(function loop(timestamp) {
                var delta = prev ? timestamp - prev : 0;
                prev = timestamp;
                var height = $window.height();

                for (var i = confetti.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                    if (confetti[i].update(height, delta)) {
                        container.removeChild(confetti[i].outer);
                        confetti.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }

                if (timer || confetti.length)
                    return frame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);

                // Cleanup
                document.body.removeChild(container);
                frame = undefined;
            });
        }
    }

    $window.keydown(function (event) {
        pointer = konami[pointer] === event.which ?
          pointer + 1 :
          +(event.which === konami[0]);
        if (pointer === konami.length) {
            pointer = 0;
            poof();
        }
    });

    if (!onlyOnKonami) poof();
});
```

```css
html {
   height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #d09d42;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #efc466, #d09d42);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```